# Can a druid PARTIALLY shapeshift?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

We know druid can

> Starting at 2nd level, they can use their action to magically assume the shape of a beast that they have seen before. they can use this feature twice. They regain expended uses when they finish a short or long rest. Their druid level determines the beasts you can transform into.

So, we know druids can use Wild Shape to turn into an animal they have seen before. The question: ***Does this have to be the full shape of an animal, or can it be part of a beast's form?***

(For example, a 16th level druid wants to obtain flight, so they turn their arms into wings)

(Another example, a druid uses Wild Shape in Wild Shape to partially transform into a horse mixed with a giant rat)

Comment: If this is true, I'll know why Doric was able to turn into an owlbear in the movie.

Comment: Owlbear is [not possible in 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200136/23547).\, although it [would not be unbalanced](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/200175/23547).

Comment: Is there some part of the Druid’s class description or wild shape feature that makes you think this is possible?

Comment: The Honor among Thieves [Thieves Gallery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tg/thieves-gallery) provides official stat blocks for the movie's main characters -- they do not use normal PC class builds, they rather use NPC-like stat blocks. According to them, Doric can turn inta an owlbear, because that is part of her polymorph feature: "Doric magically transforms into a Beast with a challenge rating of 3 or less or into an owlbear "

Answer (score 8):

## Class Features do what they say they do

You cannot turn yourself into a [liminal](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/193125/23547) beast form, because you are not given that option.

> you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before.

There is no beast you have seen before that is a humanoid with wings in place of arms.  If there was, you could use that form, but there is not, so you can't<sup>1</sup>.

The only option for your form that wild shape gives you, other than the 'standard' described beasts, is that:

> You choose whether your equipment falls to the ground in your space, merges into your new form, or is worn by it.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>If your DM has placed such a creature in your world, along with its stat block, and has for some reason given it the type of Beast, then you could see it and access the shape.</sub>